# Range Based Slider (Control both Ends)

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm looking for a clean way to produce a slider in matlab that allows me to adjust both ends of the range.  Rather than dragging a single value I would like to be able to control the end points of the slider.

I can accomplish this using two sliders with Matlab but am wondering if there is any way that this can be combined into a single control

Example showing slider that I would like.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/sliders/rangeslider.html

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7514-multi-slider) would help

Comment: I tried that, doesn't seem to work properly.  The sliders wont drag.

Comment: Oh shoot. That's an interesting question BTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished through the use of a third party java jar using Swing along with Matlabs `handle` and `javacomponent` functions.  I've adapted this from the [JIDE Common Layer (Open Source)](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)

Apparently Matlab can use standard Swing components.  This is discussed on [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/).

You will end up with a slider that looks like so:

[image: Slider Example]

Here is the code:

```
function [hcomponent, hcontainer] = createSlider
    % Add the 3rd Party Jar, should use static path but for the example, we
    % use dynamic
    javaaddpath('C:\PathToJars\jide_demo.jar')

    import com.jidesoft.plaf.LookAndFeelFactory;
    import com.jidesoft.swing.JideButton;
    import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSwingUtilities;
    import com.jidesoft.swing.RangeSlider;
    import com.jidesoft.swing.SelectAllUtils;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

    minField = JTextField();
    maxField = JTextField();
    SelectAllUtils.install(minField);
    SelectAllUtils.install(maxField);

    rangeSlider = RangeSlider(-100, 100, -100, 100);
    rangeSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    rangeSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    rangeSlider.setPaintTrack(true);
    rangeSlider.setRangeDraggable(false);
    rangeSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    rangeSlider = handle(rangeSlider, 'CallbackProperties');

    function updateValues(~, ~)
        minField.setText(num2str(rangeSlider.getLowValue()));
        maxField.setText(num2str(rangeSlider.getHighValue()));
    end

    rangeSlider.StateChangedCallback = @updateValues;

    minField.setText(num2str(rangeSlider.getLowValue()));
    maxField.setText(num2str(rangeSlider.getHighValue()));

    minPanel = JPanel(BorderLayout());
    minPanel.add(JLabel('Min'), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    minField.setEditable(false);
    minPanel.add(minField);

    maxPanel = JPanel(BorderLayout());
    maxPanel.add(JLabel('Max', SwingConstants.TRAILING), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    maxField.setEditable(false);
    maxPanel.add(maxField);

    textFieldPanel = JPanel(GridLayout(1, 3));
    textFieldPanel.add(minPanel);
    textFieldPanel.add(JPanel());
    textFieldPanel.add(maxPanel);

    panel = JPanel(BorderLayout());
    panel.add(rangeSlider, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    % hcontainer can be used to interact with panel like uicontrol
    [hcomponent, hcontainer] = javacomponent(panel, [50, 50, 200, 100], gcf);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create edit boxes on either side of your slider. Assuming that `f` is the handle for the figure and `h` is the handle for the slider you can do something like this:

```
endval1 = uicontrol('Parent',f,'Style','Edit','Position',[180,10,200,23],'String','Your number here', 'Callback', @(src,event)callback(src,event,h));
```

Of course change the position to what suits your needs and create two of them for top and bottom.

Notice how I have a callback with the following `@(src,event)callback(src,event,h)`. Here I'm passing in the handle for the slider (`h`) so I can modify it when I need.

Now for the callback:

```
function callback(src, event, h)
n = num2str(src.String);
set(h, 'Min', n);
end
```

That's an example of a callback. You will need another for the other end of course. Keep in mind that if your new `min` value is larger than either the current slider value or `max` value, it will not render until the remaining two are updated accordingly. The same of course applies to the max value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the contribution but a bit of a hack as well.